# jQuery ajax chain - how to pass response value

Tags: jquery

I can see that this matter has been discussed, but I am not making a connection with the answer given and my problem.

I am using jQuery 1.4.2 and I wish to chain two ajax calls together, passing the *response* for the first as an input to the second.

I have this:

```
 ftpReport(taskID, debugMode)
 .then((errorFlag) => {
     return updateTask(taskID, errorFlag, debugMode);  
 })
 .done(() => {});
```

The function *ftpReport* begins:

```
 function ftpReport(taskID, debugMode) {
        return $.ajax({
```

hence, I am returning this function so that it can be *then*-ned with the following call to *updateTask*

I have attempted to *return* a value from *ftpReport* (during both success and error fns) in the expectation that the returned value would be considered as *errorFlag* to the next step, of calling *updateTask*

```
 success: function () {
     return 0;
 },
 error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
     return 1;
 }
```

The value which appeared as *errorFlag* was **""**

How do I correct my code so that either the 1 or the 0 reported by *ftpReport* will be passed to *updateTask*?

Comment: "I am using  jQuery 1.4.2" — STOP! That version of jQuery no longer gets security updates. It has *publicly known* [security problems](https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-6538/product_id-11031/version_id-235481/Jquery-Jquery-1.4.2.html). Upgrade to a supported version of jQuery.

Comment: One day, hopefully :)

Comment: Try to use latest jQuery and follow this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/36255998/3835843

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The promise returned from `$.ajax` will either resolve to the successful response or trigger an exception (in the case of an error).

It does not adopt the values returned from the success and error callbacks. The return values from those are ignored.

To convert them to a promise that resolves as 1 or 0, you need to create that promise explicitly.

```
return new Promise( res => {
   $.ajax({ 
       // Other options
       success: () => res(0),
       error: () => res(1),
   });
});
```